# Hide fields from voyager Translatable

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I want to make some fields hidden from json response.
I have used Voyager multilingual feature. So my response looks like below:

```
$collection = Diet::all()->makeHidden(['description'])->translate(app()->getLocale(), 'en');
return response()->json($collection);
```

But description field included to the response. It works perfect without `->translate(app()->getLocale(), 'en')`. How I can hide description field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide these fields I've created JsonResource like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class DietCollection extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    { 
        //here we return only required fields
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'image' => $this->image,
        ];
    }
}
```

And used it like this:

```
$collection = Diet::all()->translate(app()->getLocale(), 'en');
return response()->json(DietCollection::collection($collection));
```